How to customize the completion-styles after enabling fido-mode?
After enabling fido-mode, I find the completion-styles is set to "flex". It is useful in most cases. But what if I want to switch back to the "substring" style for one completing task?
For example, I tried to the workaround using the category metadata like below. But it does not work. It is still use the "flex" style set by fido-mode.
(fido-mode 1)

(setq completion-category-overrides '((my-category (styles . (substring)))))

(let ((completion-extra-properties '(:category 'my-category)))
  (completing-read "Choose:" '("mmzn" "/mab/mbc/zn")))

In above code, when I type "mmzn", it will match to "/mab/mbc/zn" due to the "flex" match style. But if "substring" style works, it will not matches to "/mab/mbc/zn" at all.
Here is another try by using minibuffer-setup-hook. It works but always prints the return value of remove-hook, which is annoying. I wonder whether there is better way to get it done.
(fido-mode 1)

(defun my-style ()
    (setq-local completion-styles '(substring)))

(defun my-completing-test()
  (condition-case _err
      (progn
    (add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook #'my-style 100)
    (completing-read "Choose:" '("mmzn" "/mab/mbc/zn"))
    (remove-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook #'my-style))
    (quit (remove-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook #'my-style))))

(my-completing-test)




What doesn't work about what you described? 2. Have you tried putting whatever code you need in the mode hook (presumably fido-mode-hook)?


Enabling or disabling fido-mode (in an Org mode buffer, if that makes a difference) does not affect completion-styles at all: in my case it is (basic partial-completion emacs22)  with or without fido-mode. But I know virtually nothing about the completion mechanism(s) in Emacs, so I'm not sure this is helpful.

@NickD, in the icomplete--fido-mode-setup functoin, it does setup the completion-styles to `'(flex).

@Drew, thanks. Updated my question with another try with the hook. But no success yet.

Ah, I see: I don't use icomplete-mode.

It turns out there is a macro minibuffer-with-setup-hook can do the job cleanly. It internally uses the unwind-protect to handle when user types C-g.
(defun my-completing-test()
  (minibuffer-with-setup-hook
   (:append (lambda ()
     (setq-local completion-styles '(substring))))
   (completing-read "Choose:" '("mmzn" "/mab/mbc/zn"))))

